# Can in-line headphone controls interact with desktop software?

Tags: windows, audio, microsoft-surface

I want to use the volume and pause/play buttons on my headphones to adjust the volume and playback on my Surface Book.

1. Can this be done? If so, how?
2. What terms should I be searching for to research this more on my own?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 headset standards, OMTP, AHJ and Apple. While stereo audio is compatible with each other, the remote controls are not compatible with each other. You need to find out which standard your headset and laptop conform to. There are adapter from one standard to another, if you Google for them.  Even then, there is no guarantee the device will work with the headphones.